# ExtendWith attribute from Junit to NUnit

Tags: junit, nunit, testrail

I'm new to the automation space and learning as I go along so please excuse my ignorance

The literature online allows adding an attachment to a testrail testcase
in my learning I'm using eaxmples to build my automation architecture

I cannot find a NUnit example of the Junit code

Test Code available
Adding attachments to test results the test code is in Junit
and ExtendWith is not a built-in attribute in the Nunit framework

```
> @ExtendWith(TestRailTestReporterParameterResolver.class)
> public class SumTests 

> @Test
> public void canAddNumbers(TestRailTestReporter customReporter) 
> customReporter.setProperty("testrail_attachment_1", "path/to/attachment1");
> customReporter.setProperty("testrail_attachment_2", "path/to/attachment2");
```

What would this look like in NUnit, or how do I change or convert from Junit to Nunit?

Answer (score 0):

In NUnit, adding an attachment to the result is done in your test code rather than using an attribute.

```cs
TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath, "This is my attachment");
```

The file path and description will appear in the XML output. Note that your code has to actually save the attachment where you say it is.